# Node.js Serve and Modify Static File On-the-Fly

Tags: node.js

I have many `.m3u8` and `.ts` files for HLS Streaming,
and all of these are generated by another streaming software on-the-fly.
I want to add secure tokens per client to prevent unauthorized access.

NginX is used to serve HLS files, so I choose `secure_link` module to provide a hashed token generated from a combination of pathname, client IP, expire time and a salt.

The problem is, the `.m3u8` playlist must be modified to add tokens to each `.ts` file. I think NginX won't be able to modify the file, so it is the job my backend server should do.

In general, `m3u8` files are not very large, but I'm not 100% sure. Caches are not very useful because the original `.m3u8` will be generated and modified by another process on-the-fly, and for every distinct clients the token varies.

I'm currently using [Koa](http://koajs.com/). I've wrote a `Transform` stream that can read a `.m3u8` file as stream and pipe out. Should I use `fs.createReadStream` and transform and pass the stream to `ctx.res`, or use `fs.readFile` to load and modify the whole file and send? Or any other better way to do it?